# How to update ancestor state from deeply nested child component without reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, currying

I have a react app with a structure similar to the code below (but more complex). In reality, all I am changing is the data in the grandchild component (`grandchild.name` in this example). However, I have to pass getters (props) and setters (onChange) handlers on all the components along the hierarchy, making it unnecessarily complicated (especially if more nested components are added (e.g. `GreatGrandChild`).

```
// Parent
const Parent = () => {
    const [child, setChild] = useState({
        name: 'Jack',
        grandChild: {
            name: 'John'
        }
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <Child data={child} onChange={newChild => setChild(newChild)} />
        </div>
    );
};

// Child
const Child = props => {
    const handleChange = newGrandChild => {
        props.onChange({ name: props.data.name, grandChild: newGrandChild });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <GrandChild data={props.data.grandChild} onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>
    );
};

// Grand Child
const GrandChild = props => {
    const handleChange = e => {
        props.onChange({ name: e.target.name });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input type='text' onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

So how can update the parent state without adding the handleChange function in the child component. I heard "function currying" can solve this, but I don't know how to use it in this case.

P.S. I need a solution that does not include Contexts and/or Reducers, as that would be overkill for my use-case. Also, creating a "updateGrandChild" function in parent and passing it to the grandchild component won't work either, as my data structure includes an array property, where the index is dynamic.

Comment: *"So how can update the parent state without adding the handleChange function in the child component."* By using context or reducers (probably via Redux). What makes you think they're "overkill" for your use case? Your use case sounds like exactly what they're for. But if you don't want to use them, keep passing things around. *"I heard "function currying" can solve this"* I don't see how, it seems completely unrelated. Where did you hear that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "• Looks for ways to lift state-related logic higher up the component hierarchy, to keep the lower-level components simpler
o Consider using “currying” function arguments at the relevant levels
" - That was the feedback given to me by my boss when I sent him my code using the approach in the question

Comment: I suspect that those are two different pieces of feedback.

Comment: Side note: Is there some reason `onChange={newChild => setChild(newChild)}` can't just be `onChange={setChild}`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - No, I just wrote it that way to make the code easier to follow for the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { useState } from "react";

// Parent
const Parent = () => {
  const [child, setChild] = useState({
    name: "Jack",
    grandChild: {
      name: "John"
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(child, null, 2)}</pre>
      <Child data={child} onChange={setChild} />
    </div>
  );
};

// Child
const Child = ({ data, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <GrandChild data={data.grandChild} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

// Grand Child
const GrandChild = ({ data, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={data.name}
        onChange={(e) =>
          onChange((data) => ({
            ...data,
            grandChild: {
              ...data.grandChild,
              name: e.target.value
            }
          }))
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default function App() {
  return <Parent />;
}
```

[Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-violet-r4dz2q?file=/src/App.js:0-903)